# How to pass static method of the class as deleter for std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, unique-ptr

I have been trying to pass a static method of following class as `deleter` of `unique_ptr` but I couldn't figure out the correct syntax.
Please excuse if the below syntax is horribly wrong as I just started hands on with `unique_ptr`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


class Singleton {

public:

    static void deleter(Singleton* p) {
        delete p;
        std::cout << "In deleter\n" << std::endl;
    }

    static std::unique_ptr<Singleton, decltype(&Singleton::deleter)>& getInstance(void);

    void hello (void) {
       std::cout << "Hello!\n" << std::endl;
    }

    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete;

private:
    static std::unique_ptr<Singleton, decltype(&Singleton::deleter)> s_instance_;

    Singleton() { std::cout << "Constructed\n" << std::endl; }

    ~Singleton() { std::cout << "Destroyed\n" << std::endl; }

};

std::unique_ptr<Singleton, decltype(&Singleton::deleter)>&
Singleton::getInstance (void)
{
    if (s_instance_ == nullptr) {
        s_instance_ = std::unique_ptr<Singleton, decltype(&Singleton::deleter)>(new Singleton(), &Singleton::deleter);
    }

    return s_instance_;
}

std::unique_ptr<Singleton, decltype(&Singleton::deleter)> Singleton::s_instance_{nullptr};

int main ()
{
    bool some_condition = true;
    std::unique_ptr<Singleton, decltype(&Singleton::deleter)> &ins = Singleton::getInstance();

    ins->hello();

    if (some_condition) {
       ins.reset();
    }

    std::cout << "End of main\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives following error with g++ (--version == g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609)

```cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:81:0,
                 from uptr.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr() [with _Tp = Singleton; _Dp = void (*)(Singleton*)]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:200:61:   required from ‘constexpr std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) [with _Tp = Singleton; _Dp = void (*)(Singleton*); std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]’
uptr.cpp:44:89:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:159:9: error: static assertion failed: constructed with null function pointer deleter
       { static_assert(!is_pointer<deleter_type>::value,
         ^
```

Also, is there a way I can shorten `std::unique_ptr<Singleton, decltype(&Singleton::deleter)>` ? I tried using following approach before class definition but the compiler errors out for incomplete type:

```cpp
using SingletonUPtr = std::unique_ptr<Singleton, decltype(&Singleton::deleter)>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to store both type and value.  The type can do the dispatching.

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can just write this toy:

```
template<class F, F f>
struct call_t {
  constexpr operator F() const{ return f; }
};
```

which magically works.  (When you invoke it with `()`, C++ looks for a conversion to function pointer).  This is an implementation of part of `std::integral_constant` with features missing in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).  In this case, I am using it as a type that calls a constant evaluated value `f` of type `F`.  It has other (similar) uses.

Try this:

```
void foo() { std::cout << "hello world\n"; }
int main() {
  using foo_t = call_t< void(*)(), foo >;
  foo_t foo_v = {};
  foo_v(); // hello world
  foo_t{}(); // hello world
  std::cout << sizeof(foo_t) << "\n"; // 1, object is stateless
  std::cout << sizeof(&foo) << "\n"; // 4 or 8, pointer has state
}
```

The rest then looks like:

```
class Singleton {

public:

    static void deleter(Singleton* p) {
        delete p;
        std::cout << "In deleter\n" << std::endl;
    }
    using upSingleton = std::unique_ptr<Singleton, call_t<decltype(&Singleton::deleter), &Singleton::deleter> >;

    static upSingleton& getInstance(void);

    void hello() {
       std::cout << "Hello!\n" << std::endl;
    }

    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete;

private:
    static upSingleton s_instance_;

    Singleton() { std::cout << "Constructed\n" << std::endl; }

    ~Singleton() { std::cout << "Destroyed\n" << std::endl; }
};

Singleton::upSingleton&
Singleton::getInstance()
{
    if (s_instance_ == nullptr) {
        s_instance_ = upSingleton(new Singleton());
    }

    return s_instance_;
}

Singleton::upSingleton Singleton::s_instance_{nullptr};

int main()
{
    bool some_condition = true;
    Singleton::upSingleton &ins = Singleton::getInstance();

    ins->hello();

    if (some_condition) {
       ins.reset();
    }

    std::cout << "End of main\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/b1M9Gv3Y1).

Comment: Thanks, that looks neat. BTW, I have a few follow up questions to ask to understand it better. 1) What does the "toy" construct means in (C++) programming? What do we call it and what are we doing in it? 2) What does `call_t<decltype(&Singleton::deleter), &Singleton::deleter>` mean in line `using upSingleton = std::unique_ptr<Singleton, call_t<decltype(&Singleton::deleter), &Singleton::deleter> >;` What are we doing here?

Pls feel free to add any links/pointers if you want.
You may add the explanations to your above answer.

Comment: @void Do you know what a template is?  You quoted me doing a template instantiation, and you asked what I was doing.  I do not understand what you don't understand.  (2) is instantiating a template that I defined above.  What puzzles you?  Why doing that solves your problem?  How it works?  What are those `<>` doing in my C++ code?  What is the 2nd argument to `unique_ptr` template? I have no context.

Comment: I understand templates. My lack of understanding is more about proposed `call_t<decltype(&Singleton::deleter), &Singleton::deleter>` in contrast to `decltype(&Singleton::deleter)` in my question.
I'm trying to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @void One is the type of a function pointer, the other is a class instance of the `call_t` template.  The difference seems extremely large.  They are both passed as a deleter to unique ptr as the second argument.  Mine is a stateless type that when invoked with `(ptr)` calls a specific function (see the ()ed comment in my answer); the original one is a function pointer type that when invoked with `(ptr)` stores the stored function pointer.  There are other differences as well.

Comment: Again, I have absolutely no clue what you do understand, so I **cannot** describe what you don't understand without describing absolutely everything.  Please tell me what you do understand, and describe what you have worked out, even if it is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed your updated first comment, otherwise I would have asked specific questions. I knew that original one is function pointer. I couldn't understand the 2nd one because of the syntax (which is new to me). After your latest comment I understand how it works. This is what I don't understand: What are those <> doing in my C++ code? What is the 2nd argument to unique_ptr template?

Also, by looking at the template, why it is NOT `std::unique_ptr<Singleton, call_t<decltype(Singleton), &Singleton::deleter> >`

Comment: I know 2nd arg to unique_ptr template is deleter, it's just this syntax that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: "What are those <> doing in my C++ code?"
I meant after call_t.

Comment: `decltype( &Singleton::deleter)` is the type of `&Singleton::deleter`, aka `void(*)(Singleton*)`, a function pointer.  `call_t` takes a type `F` and an instance of type `F` called `f`.  `call_t< void(*)(Singleton*), &Singleton::deleter >` is a type created by the `call_t` template.  `unique_ptr`'s 2nd argument is a type.  The 2nd argument to unique ptr is not a template.  A template is not a type.  A template produces types.  Here I'm  making a type `call_t< blah, blah >` and passing it to `unique_ptr`.  The type I am making is called `call_t< void(*)(Deleter*), &Singleton::deleter >`.

Comment: @void `decltype(Singleton)` is nonsense, `Singleton` is not an expression.  `decltype` takes an expression and returns its type (basically).  `call_t< Singleton, &Singleton::deleter>` won't work, because `&Singleton::deleter` is of type `void(*)(Singleton*)` not of type `Singleton`, and `call_t` takes a type and a value of that type.  I am doing non-trivial things with templates, but your questions make me think you don't understand what templates are.  template classes are factories for types.  I use `call_t` to make a type that knows a function to call without any state in instances.

Comment: Understood!! Thank you so much!
BTW, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant seems to be supported in c++11, right? Or is it the `operator()` support that you were referring to which seems to be supported since c++14, which you used in above answer.

Comment: @void It might work in 11.  The operator() in C++14 sometimes gets in the way really.  Here I don't think it will.  Mostly I write this stuff in 17/20 now, so I use `template<auto x>` tricks to avoid the decltype stuff.  Note that there is nothing wrong with not knowing this stuff, it is just very hard to describe what you need to know when I don't know what it is you do know.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

The error is on line 44, which seems to be the definition for the `Singleton::s_instance_` variable. You don't provide the deleter function there. You should include it in the definition, like you do earlier in `getInstance`.

```
std::unique_ptr<Singleton, decltype(&Singleton::deleter)> Singleton::s_instance_{nullptr, &Singleton::deleter};
```